# Estimation of a logarithmic sum

Tags: number-theory, summation, logarithms, analytic-number-theory

I need to estimate the sum $$ \underset{r=2}{\overset{t}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\log\log r}{r}\right)^{2}. $$ I tried to use the Abel's partial summation, and I got $$ \frac{(\log\log t)^{2}}{t}-\int_{2}^{t}\frac{2\log\log r}{r^{2}\log r}dr+\int_{2}^{t}\frac{2(\log\log r)^{2}}{r^{2}}dr $$ but I don't know how I can estimate the integrals. I would like to get an estimation like $$\underset{r=2}{\overset{t}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\log\log r}{r}\right)^{2}=O\left(\frac{\left(\log\log t\right)^{2}}{t}\right)$$ or something smaller. Thank you!

Comment: The sum will converge to a positive constant when $t\to\infty$, while the expression you wish to dominate it goes to zero. Unless I am missing something, this does not make sense.

Comment: As Harald Hanche-Olsen observed, $$\sum_{r=2}^\infty \left(\frac{\log \log r}{r}\right)^2$$ is absolutely convergent. Perhaps you are asking the rate convergence, and bounds on $$\sum_{r>t} \left(\frac{\log \log r}{r}\right)^2,$$ in which case the order of magnitude is $(\log \log t)^2/t$. This allows us to write the estimate $$\sum_{r=2}^t\left(\frac{\log \log r}{r}\right)^2 = C_0 + O\left(\frac{(\log \log t)^2}{t}\right)$$ where $C_0=\sum_{r=2}^\infty \left(\frac{\log \log r}{r}\right)^2$ is a constant.